# Mocking GetStorage for testing in flutter

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, mocking, mockito

I am unit testing and widget testing my code. I have tried `mokito` and `moktail` to mock the Get storage but get this error:

```
package:get_storage/src/storage_impl.dart 47:7  GetStorage._init
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:get_storage/src/storage_impl.dart 28:7  new GetStorage._internal.<fn>
```

the class that I am testing:

```
class ShowCaseController extends GetxController {

   final box = GetStorage();
   displayAnySC(String playKey, String replayKey, GetStorage box) async {

    bool? showcasePlayStatus = box.read(playKey);
    if (showcasePlayStatus == null) {
      box.write(playKey, false);
      // box.remove(replayKey);
      box.write(replayKey, false);
      return true;
    }

    bool? showcaseReplayStatus = box.read(replayKey);
    if (showcaseReplayStatus == null) {
      box.write(replayKey, false);
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

here is one empty simple test using mock that gives error:

```
class MockStorage extends Mock implements GetStorage {}

void main() {
  group('Show case controller', () {
    final showCaseCnt = ShowCaseController();

    late bool _data;
    late MockStorage _mockStorage;
    setUp(() {
      _mockStorage = MockStorage();
      _data = showCaseCnt.displayAnySC('playKey', 'replayKey', _mockStorage);
    });

      test(
          'displayAnySC should return false when the play and replay are not null',
          () {
      
      });
  });
}
```

I have tried `@GenerateMocks([ShowCaseController])` and also added `GetStorage.init()` inside the `main` function of the test but got the same error.

P.S. I haven't seen any article or question related to mocking the GetStorage for test in Flutter. Appreciate any explanation or link that helps in this regard.

I am using the GetX package for dependency injection and state management. And using the GetStorage package for keeping the theme persistent and storing keys for notifying the app to play or replay ShowCaseView.